Graph contains two disjoint cliques
Is $$\text{2disjCLIQUEs} = 
\left\{ \langle G, k_1, k_2 \rangle : \text{ the graph $G$ contains two disjoint cliques,one of size $k_1$, and the other of size $k_2$}\right\}$$ in $\texttt{P}$ or $\texttt{NP-complete}$?
I have tried to prove it is $\texttt{NP-complete}$.
NP  Membership: A candidate solution consists of two sets of vertices: $C_1 \subseteq V$ , with  $|C_1| = k_1$ .$C_2 \subseteq V$ , with  $|C_2| = k_2$ , and  $C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$. To verify the solution we can Check that  $C_1$  induces a complete subgraph of size $k_1$ in $G$. Also we can Check that  $C_2$  induces a complete subgraph of size  $k_2$  in  $G$ .Ensure $C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$.
These checks can be done in polynomial time, so the problem is in  NP.
$\texttt{NP-hardness}$ Reduction:
To prove $\text{2disjCLIQUEs}$  is  $\text{NP-complete}$ , we reduce a known  $\text{NP-complete}$  problem to it. A natural candidate is the Clique problem.

Reduction from Clique:
The Clique problem asks: Given a graph  $G$  and integer  $k$ , does  $G$  contain a clique of size $k$?

Transform an instance  $\langle G, k \rangle$  of Clique into an instance of  $\text{2disjCLIQUEs}$ as follows:

Let  $G' = G$ .

Set  $k_1 = k$ , $k_2 = 1$.


If  $G$  contains a clique of size  $k$, then  $G'$  contains two disjoint cliques: one of size  $k_1$  (the original clique) and one of size  $k_2$  (a single vertex not in the clique).
Thus, solving $\text{2disjCLIQUEs}$ for  $\langle G', k_1, k_2 \rangle$  also solves Clique for  $\langle G, k \rangle$.Since Clique is  $\texttt{NP-complete}$ , and we can reduce it to  $\text{2disjCLIQUEs}$ in polynomial time, $\text{2disjCLIQUEs}$ is  $\texttt{NP-hard}$.$\text{2disjCLIQUEs}$ is $\texttt{NPC}$.
But my question is,  is it possible to prove it in $\texttt{P}$?

I don't know what your reduction is, but if you have proven that it is $\mathsf{NPC}$, how do you expect us to say if it is in $\mathsf{P}$ or not? What is your question? If you have doubts about your proof of $\mathsf{NP}$-completeness, describe it and ask precise questions. As is, it is unclear what you are asking.

@Nathaniel I have added more details of my reduction. And I have asked more precise question. If anything lacks, please let me know.

Your reduction fails in the case $k = |V|$ (because the two cliques would not be disjoint).
However, this is easily corrected by adding a dummy vertex.
Since the problem has been proven to be $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, it is unlikely that someone is able to prove or disprove that it is in $\mathsf{P}$, as it would solve the famous problem "$\mathsf{P}\neq \mathsf{NP}$?".

To correct the reduction(by @Nathaniel suggestion), we address the issue that arises when  $k = |V|$  (the size of the vertex set of  $G$). In this case, the entire graph is a single clique, so it is impossible to find two disjoint cliques. To fix this, we introduce a dummy vertex that is disconnected from all vertices in $G$. This ensures that one of the cliques can always contain this dummy vertex, making the two cliques disjoint.
Here is the corrected reduction:

Reduction from Clique to 2disjCLIQUEs
The Clique problem asks: Given a graph $G$  and an integer  $k$ , does  $G$ contain a clique of size  $k$?
Transform an instance  $\langle G, k \rangle$  of Clique into an instance of 2disjCLIQUEs as follows:

Construct a new graph  $G'$  by adding a dummy vertex $v_d$  to  $G$ , where  $v_d$  has no edges to any vertex in $G$ . That is,  $V(G') = V(G) \cup \{v_d\}$  and  $E(G') = E(G)$.

Set  $k_1 = k$  and $k_2 = 1$.



Correctness of the Reduction

If  $G$  contains a clique of size  $k$ :

Let  $C_1 \subseteq V(G)$  be the clique of size  $k$  in  $G$.
In $G'$ , $C_1$  is still a clique of size $k_1 = k$ , and  $C_2 = \{v_d\}$  is a clique of size  $k_2 = 1$ .
Since  $v_d$  is disconnected from all vertices in  $G$ ,  $C_1$  and  $C_2$  are disjoint cliques in  $G'$.


If  $G'$  contains two disjoint cliques of sizes $k_1 = k$  and  $k_2 = 1$ :

The clique of size  $k_2 = 1$  must be  $\{v_d\}$ , because $v_d$  is the only vertex in  $G'$  that can form a singleton clique disjoint from all vertices in  $G$ .
The other clique of size  $k_1 = k$  must lie entirely in  $G$ , and hence  $G$  contains a clique of size  $k$.




Complexity of the Reduction
The reduction involves:Adding a single vertex $v_d$ , which takes  $O(1)$  time.Setting $k_1$  and  $k_2$ , which also takes $O(1)$ time.
Thus, the reduction is polynomial in the size of $G$.
